# Docker Compose Syntax

Tags: docker, docker-compose

so I have been using docker compose for a while, I have recently come across this *new* syntax and I have no idea what it means:

For example - the compose file is located here

*http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml*

It has things such as

- &airflow-common
- <<: *airflow-common

Could somebody explain to me what that means ? It appears to be some defining config and referencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Docker feature, this is [YAML merge syntax](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) to help you [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). `&airflow-common` declares an *anchor*
for the contents after it, `<<: *airflow-common` merges contents below with the contents of the anchor. See the example:

```yaml
---
- &CENTER { x: 1, y: 2 }
- &LEFT { x: 0, y: 2 }
- &BIG { r: 10 }
- &SMALL { r: 1 }

# All the following maps are equal:

- # Explicit keys
  x: 1
  y: 2
  r: 10
  label: center/big

- # Merge one map
  << : *CENTER
  r: 10
  label: center/big

- # Merge multiple maps
  << : [ *CENTER, *BIG ]
  label: center/big

- # Override
  << : [ *BIG, *LEFT, *SMALL ]
  x: 1
  label: center/big
```